# MaterialButton is invisible when trying to add stroke width in any Layout

Tags: java, android

Here is the Code for button

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="343dp"
        android:background="@color/colortransparent"
        android:text="Select Date"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
        app:strokeColor="@color/lblue"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

Here is the image for when trying to add stroke in button

[Image With added stroke in button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0ci2.png)

And below is the code without stroke width

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="343dp"
        android:background="@color/colortransparent"
        android:text="Select Date"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
        app:strokeColor="@color/lblue"
        app:icon="@drawable/date_picker_2_icon"
        app:iconPadding="10dp"/>
```

[Image without Stroke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jttAa.png)

I tried different theme and styles and also if apply custom background which i have created in another xml file that also didn't work.
I don't understand what is the issue

Comment: i copied ur code for button without stroke into my layout editor , its working fine for me.

Comment: yest the button is working fine without stroke but why the stroke not showing when i apply the stroke width

Answer (score 2):

After some research and dinging on Google finally i found a solution which is i didn't add dependency correctly which is why all functions of button are not working properly, so here is the dependency which i was using.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

and then i change it to :-

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-rc02'
```

Now everything works fine. lol

Comment: Just don't use `alpha`, `beta` and `rc` versions, but `final` versions.

Comment: This is the latest version which i have found on this link  
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases

Comment: The assumption that "latest" means "stable" is just wrong, while it isn't a "final" release... and if you really want to use some alpha/beta/rc version, you probably should report the bugs on GitHub or the issue tracker, but not on SO (because on here, nobody will fix these bugs).